# SQL Server Bulk Insert replaces spaces with á

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, text-files, special-characters, bulkinsert

I have a raw text file where the data appears correct.
However, after I bulk insert the data into my table random spaces are replaced with á.

Before from text file:  American Science and Engineering, Inc.

After from dbo.2013_APRIL:    American Science and Engineering,áInc.

Any suggestions on why this might be occuring?  Insert statement is below....

```
BULK

INSERT SOURCE_DB.DBO.2013_APRIL
FROM 'C:\Users\a02919a\Desktop\2013_APRIL.txt'

WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
MAXERRORS = 10,
BATCHSIZE = 10,
ERRORFILE = 'C:\Users\a02919a\Desktop\2013_APRIL_errors.txt'
)
```

Comment: Did you try `DATAFILETYPE = NATIVE`, `CODEPAGE = ACP`, etc.? What is the collation of the database and table, and what is the encoding of the file (ASCII, Unicode, etc)?

Comment: did you tried specifying "DATAFILETYPE" ? i am not sure if "Native" is default or something else. but in your case you should specify "CHAR"

Comment: I did not specify Datafiletype.  My understanding is/was that Char is the default for SQL Server.  Because I'm importing a text file would Native be appropriate?  My understanding was that Native is for a table to table insert and not a text file to table insert.

Comment: Database collation = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Encoding of the file = ansci